# SQL query to fetch the result set with same status

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table 1 is as follows,

| ID | FK1_ID | FK2_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

The table with FK2 is as follows,

| ID | Type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Type1 | True |
| 2 | Type2 | True |
| 3 | Type1 | False |

The FK2_ID column is the ID column of table 2.

The expected result is, for any FK1_ID(which I have as a list of IDs), need to check all its FK2 entries in the 2nd table of Type1 and status True.

For example:
Here, I want to return YES, if all the Type1 entries are True for the specific FK1_ID. Else NO.

So, for FK1_ID with 1, the FK2 table has 3 records. Of which Type1 has 2 records. I should return YES, if both Type1 records are True, else NO.

I want accomplish this using SQL.
Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to compare a conditional count of `Status` to the full count, with a `CASE` for the final result.

```sql
SELECT
  t1.FK1_ID,
  Result = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN FK2.Status = 'True' THEN 1 END)
    THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No' END
FROM table1 t1
JOIN FK2 ON FK2.ID = t1.FK2_ID
  AND FK2.Type = 'Type1'
GROUP BY
  t1.FK1_ID;
```

A slightly shorter but less understandable version

```sql
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(NULLIF(FK2.Status, 'False'))
```

Alternatively

```sql
CASE WHEN COUNT(NULLIF(FK2.Status, 'True')) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally following your logic (how these two tables are joined) but sounds like you want to compare a total count with a conditional count so maybe something like

```
with t as (select type, count(status) as cnt,
 sum(case when status ='True' then 1 else 0 end) as truecnt
 from FK2
group by type)
select type, case when truecnt > 0 and cnt = truecnt then 'Yes' else 'No' end as MyResult
from t
```

Comment: Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: @Manikandan sorry left the end off the case expression. I updated it

Comment: Can we have a query, that lists the FK1_ID along with the current result set? Something like, 1-Type1-No, 2-Type1-Yes.